# Android Honeycomb: layout problem - hide/show FrameLayouts

Tags: android, layout, android-3.0-honeycomb, android-fragments

```
Layout 1                            Layout2

BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA   
BBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA     AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
```

The initial layout of my 2 fragments is like picture (Layout1)

there are 2 framelayouts inside a linearlayout which get filled at runtime
with fragments.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_fragment"
            android:layout_weight="1" android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

        <FrameLayout android:id="@+id/frame_map"
            android:layout_weight="3" android:layout_width="0px"
            android:paddingLeft="2dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent">
            <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/screen" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
            </RelativeLayout>
        </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I want to switch between Layout 1 <-> Layout 2.

This is currently implemented like this:

```
 FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
            android.R.anim.fade_out);

    Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(id);
    if (fragment.isHidden()) {
        transaction.show(fragment);
    } else {
        transaction.hide(fragment);
    }

    transaction.commit();
```

hiding / showing works - but does not resize the remaining fragment/framelayout to fullscreen (A)

How can I make the the remaining fragment filling the whole screen area ?
Do I have another layout or do I have to force (how?) a relayout ?

thx for any input

Comment: BBBBBBBBBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA - AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA... what?

Comment: sorry but I cannot add pictures to visualize the scenario: BBBB is fragment1 in framelayout1 AAAAA is fragment2 in framelayout2 - see layout xml. initial there are 2 fragement side by side. but I would like to show/hide one of these programmatically and have the remaining one fill the entire screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using parameters like this?

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
```